# Assembly Language multiplication overflow

Tags: assembly, pic, multiplication, pic18

This is my first post so please be gentle. I am trying to get a final answer of
0hD16BC7A and cannot even verify that I have content 0h2A in address 0x10 in the first step. I'm wondering if it has to do with the overflow commented below. Any help would be awesome I am new to this. Thank you!

```
   #include <p18f8722.inc>
   Num1H  set  0x11  ;value in 0x11 is 0hB7
   Num1L  set  0x10  ;value in 0x10 is 0hA1
   Num2H  set  0x21  ;value in 0x21 is 0h86
   Num2L  set  0x20  ;value in 0x20 is 0h88
   PR     set  0x30
          org  0
          goto start
   start:
          bcf  STATUS,C,0

         ;Num1L*Num2L
         movf  Num1L,W,0   ;[WREG] <- [0hA1] right?
         mulwf Num2L,0     ;0hA1 right?
                     ;(0hA1)*(0h88) = (oh5588) right?
         movff PRODH,PR+1  ;(0h55)->[PR+1]
         movff PRODL,PR    ;(0h88)->[PR]

         ;Num1H*Num2L
         movf  Num1H,W,0  
         mulwf Num2L,0   
         movff PRODH,PR+2  
         movf  PRODL,W,0 
         addwf PR+1,F,A  

         ;Num1L*Num2H
         movf   Num1L,W,0  
         mulwf  Num2H,0   
         movf   PRODL,W,0 
         addwfc PR+1,F,A 
         movf   PRODH,W,0 
         addwfc PR+2,F,A

         ;Num1H*Num2H
         movf   Num1L,W,0  
         mulwf  Num2H,0   
         movf   PRODL,w,0 
         addwfc PR+2,F,A  ;Is the problem because I have 0h13D here?
         movlw  0         ;How do I handle the overflow?
         addwfc PRODH,W,A 
         movwf  PR+3,0
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever processor this is for, but IMO you might consider using `0x` for hex all the time in your source files (both code and comments), just for clarity.  It's not confusing or anything, but mixing `0x` and `0h` prefixes in the same file makes your brain have to switch gears every time it goes from one prefix to the other.  If the convention for your assembler is `0x`, I'd go with that.  FWIW.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: looks like it is a pic microcontroller.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was concerned about keeping addresses and content within the address separate.

Comment: It is. It's a PIC 18.

Comment: `0h` is often a suffix. I've never seen anyone uses `0h` at the beginning of the number. So it should be `0Ah` or `0x0A`